# GIMP; Transfer source tonal/color profile to a second image

Tags: color, gimp, color-conversion, color-reproduction

In GIMP, is there a programmatic/algorithmic way to transfer the color/tonal profile of one image to another when they have similar subjects?

I have this image:

[image]

And then this image:

[image]

Similar subjects but quite different tonality, coloring, grading, etc.

Is there a way to transfer the tonal/color profile of the first image onto the second image so that there's more congruence between them? I've seen a Sample Colorize tool in the Colors options that I thought would be useful, but it just does an operation similar to the Colorize tool and seems to use a limited palette. I could pick around in the Curves dialogue by eye but was just wondering if there's a plugin or method or tool that would do it programmatically and more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Try Color transfer filter in G'MIC collection.

This demo in YouTube is quite impressive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zl57jEJazZE&feature=youtu.be

I tried the basic version only. It seemed at least to increase the colorfulness of the faces in the office session image:

[image]

I guess seeing automatically the sameness of the contents of different images needs something radically more advanced. I am not the programmer of this add-on, but there's nothing about subject recognition in the filtering dialog. I guess G'MIC "Color transfer" tries to equalize statistical color distributions to meet some (maybe a complex one) criteria, but it doesn't care if one of the images has people and other has something else.

Comment: Very helpful of you. Thanks. I'm downloading it now and will try out that filter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I and an associate have provided a web app which undertakes this task but also allows for tuning of the processing.

https://www.dustfreesolutions.com/CT/CT.html

The theory behind this app and C++ source code and be found here.

https://github.com/TJCoding/Enhanced-Image-Colour-Transfer-2